# Change currency in Craft CMS using the Charge plugin

Tags: plugin-charge

Okay so I have [Charge](https://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/charge) setup with Stripe. I have entered in the connection details and selected the currency to pounds in the Stripe credentials in the plugin settings. However when I view the charges the money is correct in pounds but the symbol is a dollar sign... I need to change it to the pound symbol.

Has anyone come across with this issue and have I missed something of.. EG. Config file needs currency symbol override etc.

Hope this makes sense.

Comment: Never used Charge, but in Stripe have you set the default currency as in the picture in step #3 here? https://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/charge/usage/quickstart/stripe-config

Answer (score 1):

Developer of [Charge](https://squarebit.co.uk/software/craft/charge) here.

It sounds like you could be running an older version of the Charge.  There was a *display* bug on the overview page that would set the currency symbol incorrectly for some setups.

This is fixed in the latest versions, so make sure you're running 2.2.0 or above.

Note - this fix won't affect any previously recorded payments that were in a non-default currency, but this is purely a display bug on the *overview* page - if you go into the detail view for the specific Charges, they'll be correctly showing the relevant currency, and all the details visible to the end-customers and on Stripe will also be correct.